# PostgreSQL - How to replace empty field with any string?

Tags: postgresql, null, coalesce

I'm trying to replace some empty (NULL) fields, which I get as a result of my query, with any string I want. Those empty fields are placed in a "timestamp without timezone" column. So I tried to use COALESCE function, but no result (I got error: invalid input syntax for timestamp: "any_string":

```
select column1, coalesce(date_trunc('seconds', min(date)), 'any_string') as column2
```

What could be wrong?

Table:

```
╔════╦═════════════════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ id ║        date         ║        date2        ║
╠════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ 2013-12-17 13:54:59 ║ 2013-12-17 09:03:31 ║
║  2 ║ 2013-12-17 13:55:07 ║ 2013-12-17 09:59:11 ║
║  3 ║ 2013-12-17 13:55:56 ║ empty field         ║
║  4 ║ 2013-12-17 13:38:37 ║ 2013-12-17 09:14:01 ║
║  5 ║ 2013-12-17 13:54:46 ║ empty field         ║
║  6 ║ 2013-12-17 13:54:46 ║ empty field         ║
║  7 ║ 2013-12-17 13:55:40 ║ empty field         ║
╚════╩═════════════════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

Sample query:

```
select q1.id, q2.date, q3.date2
from (select distinct id from table1) q1
left join (select id, date_trunc('seconds', max(time)) as date from table2 where time::date = now()::date group by id) q2 on q1.id = q2.id
left join (select id, date_trunc('seconds', min(time2)) as date2 from table1 where time2:date = now()::date group by id) q3 on q1.id = q3.id
order by 1
```

And the matter is to replace those empty field above with any string I imagine.

Comment: Does your query work without the *replace empty field* part?

Comment: Yes, it works. Only thing I want to achieve is to replace those empty dates with any string I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply cast timestamp to text using `::text`

```
select column1, coalesce(date_trunc('seconds', min(date))::text, 'any_string') as column2
```

Comment: I've tried that, but still it returns empty fields instead of text :(

Comment: select q1.id, coalesce(q2.date::text, 'any_string'), coalesce(q3.date2::text, 'any_string') from ...

Answer (score 1):

The [`date_trunc()` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-datetime.html) returns a `timestamp`, thus you cannot fit a string like `any_string` in the same column.

You'll have to pick a format and [convert the resulting date to string](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-formatting.html), though of course it'll no longer be usable as date.

Comment: I've converted date_trunc() using to_char() function, but now it's giving me empty fields like before, without error:
coalesce(to_char(date_trunc('seconds', min(date)), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'any_string')

Comment: I [cannot reproduce it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d6661/3). You should post a full self-complete example, including table creation, sample data and actual query.

Answer (score -1):

the `coalesce` function only works on the integer data type. It will not work on any other data type .

In one of cases I used to convert a varchar data type to integer inside the `coalesce` function by using `_columnName_ :: integer` syntax .
But in your case i dont think so that time stamp will be converted to the integer data type.